# Find text in parentheses but only if a substring is present

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I need to flag sentences when there is text in parentheses but only if a certain word (`myword`) is present.

These are some possible options of the word appearing inside parentheses:

```
(random text myword)
(random text myword random text)
(myword random text)
(myword, random text)
(random text, myword random text)
```

The output should contain parentheses and text inside.

UPD: The instances above might be surrounded by text with parentheses, i.e. `(random text) random text (random text myword) random text (random text)`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/4736/3001761.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use `\(.*myword.*\)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uqd3SV/1)

or for your update:

`\([^(]*myword[^)]*\)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uqd3SV/2)

Comment: The problem with this solution is that I have some other text around `(random text myword)` which may contain parentheses too.

Comment: @aviss: Add another possibility. With regex, we have to be clear on what we want and what we reject.

Comment: Hmm, have actually realised that it doesn't work with this: `(random text) random text (random text) random myword (random text)` when myword appears in random text.

Comment: I guess this should work - `\([^(|)]*myword[^)|(]*\)`?

Comment: inside `[]`, `|` is not the "or", but is the single char `'|'`.